# How to use F# with mono on linux?

Tags: linux, f#, mono

I have had difficulty figuring out how to use F# on Linux - I would really appreciate help.

Comment: Define 'use' please. Do you want to compile F#, or simply run an executable you compiled on Windows?

Comment: I want to compile code written in F#.

Comment: Do you have mono installed?  Have you downloaded F#?  Have you run "install-mono.sh"?  Where are you at in the process, and what trouble are you having?

Comment: Which prcoess are we talking about? If I found a process I would probably not have had to ask the question :(

Where is this process documented?

Comment: Go here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b55f0532-ac3c-4106-918c-5586a953a7da&displaylang=en
Download fsharp.zip.  Unzip and run the install-mono.sh.

Answer (score 8):

Well, My box: Ubuntu, mono, fsharp, emacs and [fsharp-mode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsharp-mode)

with fsharp-mode you have

1. highlighting
2. interactive console
3. emacs :-).

Also, you can try to install .net 2.0 on wine (with winetricks for example) together with sharpdevelop 2.2.

Personaly i've decided to use emacs and fsharp-mode.

UPDATE:

another option is to use regular editor such as kate in OCaml mode but it can be inconvenient due to differences between languages.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar question with detailed answers:
[How to get F# working with Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832552/how-to-get-f-working-with-mono/832953#832953)

Simple example of compilation command can be found at here:
http://gist.github.com/raw/144209/02f2f4450ed8261c5e4f3c18055de89ff0db9612/FebKit.fs

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old now, but this can help other people. In CodePlex there is a project called F# cross-platform packages and samples.  It has some linux packages (and also for Mac). [Click here](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/releases/view/55463) for the download page.

Answer (score 0):

Google for F#, and the very first entry that comes up is http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/ - and one of the first things on that page is:

Download F# now --> Visual Studio 2010, or CTP Update for Visual Studio 2008 or standalone compiler+library ZIP, for Mono and Windows

Have you installed that, and is something not working for you?

Comment: I am really unsure why this answer has so many votes... No Version of Visual Studio is able to run on linux. This answer would be ok, for a question regarding Windows. But for this question it is plain wrong.

Comment: Visual Studio isn't required.  It's one of the options there, but not the only option.  For Linux, you'll want the standalone compiler + library zip, not Visual Studio.

Comment: And the page has changed since this was posted - it's now at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/release.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Keke, this is a late answer, but I have a post that explains how you can install F# under Linux and Mac systems.  It assumes you understand how to compile software for Linux.

Here it is: http://blog.gnucom.cc/2009/installing-f-on-ubuntu-8-04/

Let me know what you think.